# php startup issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run php artisan migrate command and it is showing me this error. I have no clue what to do with this. Earlier it was working fine but now this. I also have php 7 installed.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Probably a problem with your PHP installation. Please re-install PHP

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the fact that you need `PDO PHP Extension`:

> However, if you are not using Homestead, you will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:
>
> 1. PHP >= 5.6.4
> 2. OpenSSL PHP Extension
> 3. PDO PHP Extension
> 4. Mbstring PHP Extension
> 5. Tokenizer PHP Extension
> 6. XML PHP Extension

Run the following to install the required(and additional) `PHP` modules:

Centos:

```
yum -y install php70w php70w-bcmath php70w-cli php70w-common php70w-gd php70w-ldap php70w-mbstring php70w-mcrypt php70w-mysql php70w-odbc php70w-pdo php70w-pear php70w-pear-Benchmark php70w-pecl-apc php70w-pecl-imagick php70w-pecl-memcache php70w-soap php70w-xml php70w-xmlrpc
```

Debian:

```
# 1. Enable
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
# 2. Install
sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-common php7.0-cli php-pear php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-gmp php7.0-intl php7.0-imap php7.0-json php7.0-ldap php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-ps php7.0-readline php7.0-tidy php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-xsl
```

Tested the installation on `debian`. Additionally look for following references:

1. Purge and install `php7`: https://askubuntu.com/a/705893/536547
2. Laravel Installation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation.

Comment: No I am not using homestead. Does it mean my php files have been interrupted and installing php 7 again will work?

Comment: I think you need to install additional required modules, instead of reinstalling.

Comment: Mine is linux mint 17. Do I need to enable repos before running yum?

Comment: update the answer, you need to use `debian` instructions. Please kindly check it out